# InstagramApiSharp. Не срабатывают прокси

Tags: c#, proxy

Всем привет. Использую библиотеку InstagramApiSharp. Подключаю прокси, никаких ошибок не происходит, но когда я вхожу в аккаунт, то Инстаграм присылает попытку входа из моего текущего местоположения. То есть прокси не срабатывают. Хотя они рабочие. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Не понимаю, с апи проблема или я что-то не так делаю.

```
 var userSession = new UserSessionData
        {
            UserName = username,
            Password = password
        };


        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy()
        {
            Address = new Uri($"http://ip:port"),
            BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
userName: "login",
password: "password")
        };
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = wp
  
            
        };

      

        var InstaApi = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder()
            .SetUser(userSession)
            .UseLogger(new DebugLogger(LogLevel.Exceptions))
            .UseHttpClientHandler(httpClientHandler)
            .Build();


        //InstaApi.UseHttpClientHandler(GetHttpHandler());
        //InstaApi.HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://i.instagram.com/");

        var result = await InstaApi.LoginAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, это не работает только если использовать версию .Net Core ниже версии .Net Core 2.1. До версии .Net Core 2.1 класс HttpClientHandler использовал старые протоколы http.